# Tag rename request: [remote-play] -> [ps4-remote-play]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

After asking a question where I used the [remote-play](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-play) tag, I was a bit worried that it might get edited and removed. The reason is that "remote play" sounds like a generic term (the act of playing a game remotely, via LAN/WAN or the Internet).

After looking at the questions that are using this tag, they all mention the PS4 console. Because of this, I want to request a rename that uses the official application title:

#### Android

[image]

#### iOS

[image]

#### Windows and macOS

[image]

The change is pretty simple, [remote-play](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-play) is renamed to [ps4-remote-play](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps4-remote-play)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done!

- [remote-play](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-play) -> [ps4-remote-play](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps4-remote-play)