# Tag rename request: [ps4-remote-play] -> [ps-remote-play]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Back in October 2019, I requested the tag rename of [remote-play to ps4-remote-play](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14677/tag-rename-request-remote-play-ps4-remote-play), but now PlayStation has renamed the app once again to PS Remote Play due to the same app also supporting the PS5 console.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems accurate, I've renamed the tag to [ps-remote-play](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps-remote-play).